# Port forwarding not working on netis router

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, webserver, port

I am using a netis WF2419E router. My server computer is on `192.168.1.4` and I have set up virtual servers in the router to forward external port `80-80` to internal port `80-80` for IP address `192.168.1.4` (all protocols).

When I go to `192.168.1.4` on a browser using my PC (which is connected to the same router), I can see my server's web page just fine. However, when I go to my public IP address, it does not work.

I used https://canyouseeme.org/ and it says, `Error: I could not see your service on x.x.x.x on port (80)` (of course, it shows my actual IP in place of `x.x.x.x`).

I tried ping testing my IP with https://www.site24x7.com/ping-test.html and it is pinging okay. I also restarted the server and router multiple times.

It was working fine with my old D-Link router, but not working with my new netis router. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Please look at the existing posts on this topic ("Related" section, also search for "NAT hairpin").

Comment: @grawity I'm not really networking savvy, but what I can gather about NAT hairpin is that it could be a problem only for machines in the same network trying to access the public IP. However, my IP is not accessible from outside the network either. As mentioned, I tried https://canyouseeme.org/ and also tried visiting the IP from my phone using mobile network instead of wifi. Doesn't work.

Comment: Aha, I somehow missed that part of your post.

Comment: @grawity No problem. I also checked the related posts, but could not find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I had to edit the `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` file in my server and change the line `static routers=192.168.0.1` to `static routers=192.168.1.1`. I think it was auto configured with my old router (which was at `192.168.0.1`) and that's why it wasn't working with the new one (which is at `192.168.1.1`). Problem fixed!

Update: After I changed the `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` file, Apache started causing some problems. Instead of trying to fix this one however, I just reinstalled Raspbian and now everything seems to be working fine with the fresh installation.

Comment: Do you even need the `static ...` line at all? This information is already delivered via DHCP anyway, that's the whole point.

Comment: @grawity I don't know really, I think I just uncommented a built-in line to set a static IP for the server before (because my old router did not have DHCP address reservation). As I said, I'm not that knowledgeable on networking, so most of the time I'm just following instructions found on the internet, hehe.